# Flutter SharedPrefences Api 33

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Buenas tardes y gracias de antemano.
Estoy empezando un proyecto en Flutter, en version anterior a Api 33 funciona genial, pero en Api 33 no lee bien el fichero creado con Shared....
si consulto datos, encuentra ,muestra "SI". en cambion, no muestra el valor de la variable.Alguna idea?

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();    
if(prefs.containsKey("usuario")){
          String? value = prefs.getString('usuario');
          print("CCCCCCCCCCCCC  "+value!);
          print("SI");
        }else{
          print ("no");
        }
```

Al guardar, el fichero se genera en el emulador, lo abro y tiene los datos.

```
      SharedPreferences preferences = await                                                     SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  preferences.setString('id', id);
  preferences.setString('usuario', usuario);
  preferences.setString('email', email);
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de shared_preferences estás usando?

Comment: shared_preferences: ^2.2.1

Comment: he probado otras librerias y con todas pasa lo mismo, pero solo con Pixel 7, he probado con Pixel 6, tambien con Api 33 y funciona

Comment: Edita y por favor muestra la forma en la que estás guardando este valor, si el log muestra algún error también sería bueno mostrarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es correcto, pero el problema es simplemente que el valor de `usuario` al guardarlo en la preferencia no tiene valor, debes asegurar que la fuente de datos obtiene el valor en API 33 o posterior.

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  preferences.setString('id', id);
  preferences.setString('usuario', usuario);
  preferences.setString('email', email);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ya esta solucionado.

Comment: Era el valor de usuario verdad? @bcnpmt